# I changed my phone number and can't verify my Gmail account

Tags: gmail, sms, verification

I changed my phone number and can't verify my Gmail account.  How do I fix this?
I know my password. I've tried accessing my alternative email. Nothing is working.  I can't regain access to my old number.
How do I access my account?

Answer (score -1):

From http://www.google.ca/contact/

Call Google at 650-253-0000
Talk to a Human
Press <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: Can you link to where this official phone number is listed?  There are a lot of scammers advertising "Google support" services, so I'd like to have evidence that this is legit.  Thanks!

Comment: http://www.google.ca/contact/

Comment: Have you tried calling this number for account access issues? Did you get the help you needed?